# Remove gray header on Search Result page on Wordpress

Tags: search

I'm new here, and new using Wordpress I'm creating a website, https://www.maispersona.com and I'm trying to modify my search page layout. (You can get into the website and search something to see)

I'm using the Elementor plugin. But I'm getting an issue when I try to remove a grey colored div, with a search result information on the search page result.

Can you help me please? Sorry for my English is not my native language.

[image: Here on the picture, you can see the header of the search result page, I want to remove this gray div and the information "n Search Results Found]

Here on the picture, you can see the header of the search result page, I want to remove this gray div and the information "n Search Results Found

Thank You a lot

Answer (score 0):

Put this css in your style. For Particular page use class **"search-results"** and you can replace **"RED" color with your color.** if css not apply then try with "!important" like **background-color: red !important;**

```
.search-results .page-header {
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you like replace color with image then you can use css property **"background-image"**.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, actually I wanted to remove completely the div instead of just changing the color :) but this solution is useful also. I solved the solution in another way: I went to my wordpress root folder on header.php and I removed this line (OceanWP theme) <?php do_action( 'ocean_page_header' ); ?> and the header disappeared like I wanted. :) Thank youuu.

Comment: but you can remove this line then header will remove from all site pages. your Que. is remove header only search result page.

Comment: I´m using elementor plugin to build all other pages so I´m not using the OceanWP header actually that´s why this solutions works for me :). Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and a wee mod (see below) was the fix:

```
.search-results .page-header {
    display: none;
}
```